# Disk usage in Perl Core

Tags: perl, perl-core

I’m looking for a way to check the remaining free space on a disk within Perl. I can’t use CPAN since I have to deploy the script on many servers with different versions of Perl, and I can’t change it because my team leader ordered me that way.

Any idea? I tried `File::stat` but I can’t use it on `D:\` (the script runs on Windows versions).

Thanks!

Comment: If you can't use CPAN, and you can't use PAR, then you shouldn't be deploying Perl code. Just silliness.

Comment: I found a way using some horrible parsing method on `dir` system command

Answer (score 0):

```
fsutil volume diskfree C:
```

For Windows servers you can run this cmd command from system() method.

Comment: It requires admin rights, I can’t deal with that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/perl_win_disk_mon.txt.html read this article. There is more info there than just to know free disk space in windows server.
P.S. Don't worry about Russian language, it's only intro.